# How to configure Rollup to allow multiple entry points as well as CJS and EJS compilation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollup

I wish to be able to import my library with multiple entry points (like ABC/X, ABC/Y, ABC/Z). I've been able to do the same with the help of 'rollup-plugin-multi-input' plugin.

But now I also wish to compile it in both ECMA and CommonJS. I've not been able to find any relevant documentation for this, and most results I get are for imports from the library (like import {x} from "abc"). No CJS compilation is creating troubles for me in React testing.

How do you provide multiple entry points at the same time compile in ECMA and CommonJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in a couple projects that I bundle for both node and browser environments.

Optionally, first, in your `package.json`, make sure that you have a `main` and `module` set like so:

```json
{
    "main": "package-cjs.js",
    "module": "package-esm.js"
}
```

This will be used to name the bundles and is a better alternative to hardcoding the names.

Then, in your `rollup.config.js`, it should look something like the following (note that I don't know how your input looks like so you can leave yours as it is if it's different).

```js
import pkg from "./package.json";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";

export default {
    input: "./src/index.ts",
    external: [],
    plugins: [
        commonjs(),
    ],
    output: [{
        file: pkg.main,
        format: "cjs",
        exports: 'default'
    }, {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: "esm",
    }],
};
```

Note that in the `file` property of each export we use the name from the `package.json`. You can also just set this as a string if you don't want to do that step.

Now when you run your Rollup build you should see bundles for both the main and module.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but how do you add multiple entry points with this method?

Comment: @NirmalKhedkar I'm sorry I thought by the phrasing of your question that you had it figured out. Can you post your current `rollup.config.js` in the question body so I can update my answer more accurately?